# Prevent webview from loading some URLs

Tags: java, android, webview

I create a android app that host website, the website loads some external links "URL".

I need to block some URLs that store in file on `/res/raw/` from loading in webview.

I try override `shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url)`, but I don't know how use it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,android.webkit.WebResourceRequest))

method of the `WebViewClient`

> Give the host application a chance to take over the control when a new url is about to be loaded in the current WebView.If WebViewClient is provided, return `true` means the host application handles the url, while return `false` means the current WebView handles the url.

in code:

```
    public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("http://Your_website_url")) {
             // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
             return false;
        }

        // reject anything other
        return true;
    }
}


mWebview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());  //set the webviewClient
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to override the method `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` (see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest))) of your `WebViewClient`, rather than the one you are overriding. Just return `false` if you want to load the page; `true` if you want to block loading.

Comment: good but in this case how can block a list of site's within the file

Comment: You have to implement the logic. Load the list inside of a List and then check that list in shouldOverrideUrlLoading